# Why is @someone not recognized everywhere in a page?

Tags: discussion, users

What is the rationale for the fact that `@someone` used on a page is not being matched against any user which has taken part in a question (whether this the **question** itself, an **answer** or a comment)?

I would find it easier to be able to mention **anywhere** (on the question page)  that *`@janedoe` said this and that but `@johndoe` was more correct* and having them being poked (since their name was mentioned) which could trigger a considerable improvement of their comment/answer/question (or a chaotic exchange).

Today this is usually a plain @someone in a sentence which does not do much, and particularly does not help to ether immediately identify the user, or warn him/her that there is something going on around what she/he wrote.

EDIT: @AdamDavis answer shows that I did not emphasize enough that my question was about "anywhere on the page") and not only comments, so I will improve it and he will never know because @AdamDavis was not recognized...

Comment: Chaotic exchange? . . . Comments aren't boxing rings.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ.: exactly - I wanted to provide an alternate outcome for that functionality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alert scope is intentionally limited to avoid long discussions between multiple people. If you have a comment and you really need several people to review it and respond, you should probably be posting a few smaller comments to the relevant posts, or an answer or entirely new question.

Comments are meant to clarify or follow up on a question or answer, not to hold discussions on tangents.

Comment: Yes, this is why I also mentioned *answers* and *question* in my question (answers are obvious, the question case would be useful for an edit (*EDIT: following `@johndoe` answer, here is the consolidated code...*)

Comment: @WoJ Ah, I see.  Alerts don't work at all inside posts, only comments, and only if that person has already commented.  The answers were intended, by design, to be strongly decoupled, so if one were to be deleted or edited it didn't change the other one, and so voting could be more compartmentalized, particularly in choosing an accepted answer. Alerts inside posts would further make this more like a discussion and social network than it is now.  Perhaps that's desirable to some, but it is intentionally designed to prevent that from happening.